# how to difference components in angular

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with two component child, and I want to know which child generates an event, my try is with binding, but doesnt work:

parent:

```
  <span> FIRST CHILD </span>
  <childComponent [childName]=childName1></childComponent>
  <span> SECOND CHILD </span>
  <childComponent [childName]=childName2></childComponent>

  export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    childName1: string ="child1";
    childName2: string ="child2";

  }
```

in child:

```
 <button (click)=event($event)> button </button>


 export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

       @Input() childName: string;
 }
 ...
 event():void{
      console.log(this.childName);
 }
```

Comment: What is your purpose? Is it to receive the event in the parent component?

Comment: no, child component is a mat-table and the event reloads it

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
<my-child (event)="onChildEvent($event, 'child1')"></my-child>
<my-child (event)="onChildEvent($event, 'child2')"></my-child>
```

This way the child doesn't need to be involved.

Answer (score 1):

> Solution to your problem, have a look

[StackBlitz: Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-differenciate-components-in-angular)

> Child fires the event, plus lets the parent know which child fired it

1. This method even works for dynamically generated child components
2. Also child can send extra data along with identification at once.